# How to give a dropdown a specific value after filling it with database values in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, database

I have in my Views.py a query which I'm using to populate a dropdown. It works well, except that I need it to show a specific value, stored in a variable that corresponds to the user's selection.

Let's say we have a dropdown which is filled from a database ('world') using the following query:

```
regions = world.objects.values_list("regions").distinct()
```

So this fills my dropdown with regions names. If the user has previously selected 'Europe' (stored in r2 variable), how do I amend this query so it selects 'Europe' after having filled the dropdown?

Edit:

html code:

```
<select id="regions" name="r2" onclick="GetSelectedText()" onChange="form.submit();">
    {% for item in regions %}
    <option val="{{ item.name_reg }}"> {{ item }} </option>    
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedText(){
      var r = document.getElementById("regions");
      var result_r = r.options[r.selectedIndex].text;

      document.getElementById("result_r").innerHTML = result_r;
      }
  </script>
```

Views.py:

```
def MyView(request):
    result_r = request.POST.get('r2')
    print(result_r)
    if request.method == 'POST' and result_r != None:
        query_results = world.objects.all()
        regions = world.objects.values_list("name_reg").distinct()


        query_results_dict = {
        'query_results': query_results,
        'regions': regions,
        }

        return render(request,'home.html', query_results_dict)
```

Comment: You should update your question and add relevant part of the code where you render the values from the queryset to the dropdown widget. Are you using `forms` or are you directly rendering inside an html template?

Comment: Ok, thought it would be straightforward, this is why I didn't do it. Anyway, I just edited my question. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: What is the variable that is holding the preselected value? There is no `sel_region` variable in your `query_results_dict` dictionary.

Comment: My bad, just replaced it with the actual variable which is r2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing a `context` variable called `r2` (assuming it is the same datatype as `item.name_reg`) to your template you can select the option with an `ifequal` statement:

```
<select name="regions" id="regions">
    {% for item in regions_list %}
    <option val="{{ item.name_reg }}" {% ifequal item.name_reg r2 %}selected{% endif %}> {{ item }} </option>    
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: I thought this would work but unfortunately no. Every time it submits the form, it is the first choice of the dropdown that gets selected. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I had to replace 'item.name_reg' by 'item' in: <option val="{{ item }}" {% ifequal item r2 %} selected {% endif %}> {{ item }} </option>    
Now it works, thanks.